# How do we uninstall the Amadeus Digital DNA extension from Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, uninstallation, amadeus

I have uninstalled the app with the .msi installer and even then I could see the extension still installed in chrome.

Could you let me know how to uninstall the extension completely from machine and chrome ?

I have deleted the extension ID of Amadeus from chrome extensionallowlist an extensionforcelist of registry and even then extension is installed in chrome.

Comment: Did you clear registry both in HKCU and HKLM roots? Also, did you remove the extension in `chrome://extensions` page?